# Finding the right method to validate a model?

Tags: validation, robust, methodology

I am doing a decision-making project to determine political preferences by answering questions about every candidate's program and then scoring these questions by themes (ecology, economy) for each candidate with the difference between their scores and the score of the voter. Then we apply [Electre ranking method][1] (there is also a good example of how to use this method from [Buccanan, Sheppard and Vanderpooten here][2]).

I want my model to be valid. Yet it seems it is not. Indeed, on ten attempts, one candidate model has always been dominated. My supervisor has asked me to search for the robustness of my method,  especially the "data robustness" and sensibility. Although I'm able to create models I don't know how to validate these models.

**My question is, having all my matrices, what method should I use to validate my model?**

I think there is bias in my model because we do not ask the same number of questions for each candidates for instance.

Therefore :

- how to be sure I'm not disadvantaging a candidate ?
- how to calculate the [data robustness][3] of the model?
- how to calculate the sensibility of the model ?

**Here are the results by candidates according to themes, the data I have to compute**. I have other sets of it. It comes from 105 questions asked to a voter from the program of 7 candidates with different number of questions for each of them and different weights the voter chose himself.
\begin{array}{llllllllll}
           & Ecologie & Travail & Interna. & Instit. & Santé & Eco. & Social & Sécurité & Education \\
Pinel      & 19       & 24      & 31            & 35          & 14    & 29       & 17     & 15       & 9         \\
Bennahmias & 19       & 23      & 26            & 43          & 14    & 29       & 11     & 15       & 9         \\
de Rugy    & 25       & 25      & 26            & 49          & 14    & 37       & 11     & 15       & 16        \\
Valls      & 19       & 23      & 26            & 42          & 19    & 29       & 11     & 15       & 9         \\
Peillon    & 19       & 23      & 27            & 40          & 20    & 30       & 15     & 15       & 8         \\
Montebourg & 19       & 20      & 26            & 47          & 19    & 35       & 17     & 18       & 9         \\
Hamon      & 23       & 17      & 30            & 43          & 15    & 27       & 11     & 23       & 9         \\
Electeur   & 37       & 51      & 52            & 78          & 28    & 58       & 25     & 30       & 17       
\end{array}

This comes from, for instance for the $ecologie$ theme :

$$Score_{theme}(elector, candidate_i)=\sum_{q\in ecologie}|w_q*response_{q,candidate_i}+w_q*response_{q,elector}|$$

## The method applied to know which candidate are better than other candidates : Electre IS

I then apply Electre IS method to get the "matrice de surclassement".

$$c_{theme}(candidat_i,candidat_j)=\begin{cases}
1 &\mbox{if } Score_{theme}(elector, candidate_i)+seuil\ge Score_{theme}(elector, candidate_j)\\
0 &\mbox{else}
\end{cases}$$

Then we do the general concordance matrix :

$$C(candidate_i, candidate_j)=\frac{1}{\sum_{t\in theme} w_t}\sum_{t\in theme} w_{t}c_{t}(candidate_i, candidate_j)$$

And general discordance matrix :

$$D_{candidat_i,candidat_j}=
\begin{cases}
1 \mbox{ si }\exists t, Score_{t}(electeur, candidat_i)+v_t< Score_{t}(electeur, candidat_j)\\
0 \mbox{ sinon }
\end{cases}$$

To get the "matrice de surclassement" which let us know which candidates is better than the other. ($s_j$ is the threshold from which $candidate_i$ is said has better than $candidate_j$ provided by the elector)

$${candidat_i}S{candidat_j}=
\begin{cases}
0 \mbox{ if } D_{candidate_i,candidate_j} = 1 \mbox{ or } C(candidat_i, candidate_j) < s_{maj}\\
1 \mbox{ else }
\end{cases}$$

With the data provided above we have :

\begin{array}{llllllll}
& pinel       & bennahmias & derugy & valls & paillon & montebourg & hamon &       \\
pinel      & TRUE                  & TRUE               & FALSE           & TRUE               & FALSE                & FALSE & FALSE \\
bennahmias & FALSE                 & TRUE               & FALSE           & TRUE               & FALSE                & FALSE & FALSE \\
derugy   & FALSE                 & TRUE               & TRUE            & TRUE               & FALSE                & FALSE & FALSE \\
manuel       & FALSE                 & TRUE               & FALSE           & TRUE               & FALSE                & FALSE & FALSE \\
paillon    & FALSE                 & TRUE               & FALSE           & TRUE               & TRUE                 & FALSE & FALSE \\
montebourg.  & FALSE                 & TRUE               & FALSE           & TRUE               & FALSE                & TRUE  & FALSE \\
hamon       & FALSE                 & FALSE              & FALSE           & FALSE              & FALSE                & FALSE & TRUE 
\end{array}

$pinelSderugy$ here shows $TRUE$ means that $pinel$ beats $derugy$.

But how to test my model to be sure the values it gives are true ?
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELECTRE
[2]: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.493.6585&rep=rep1&type=pdf
[3]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "data robustness"?

Comment: @whuber I4m so sorry, is skweeness better ?

Comment: I am asking because I have no idea what you might mean--no guesses at all.  Please try to describe what this term is intended to refer to.

Comment: @whuber It means the possibility for the actual result not to be modified by some data variations and to what extent.

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustesse_(statistiques)

Comment: @Marine1 For American's like me can you translate the french in the wikipedia link?

Comment: It sounds like you intend "robust" in the sense of robust statistics or robust procedures.  *Data* are not ordinarily considered robust in these senses. Moreover, robustness is usually considered a qualitative characteristic of the procedures you use: it's not quantified, except in limited ways (such as breakdown points of specific procedures), and therefore is not something one "calculates."  In the tables you have posted, what are data and what are the "actual results"?  How are the results computed from the data?

Comment: Even though I have read a several books and quite a few papers on robustness in statistics (and have taught classes on some of the basics of it, so I presume it's not that I lack understanding of robustness), I really have no clear idea what this question is actually asking.

Comment: @whuber I've updated, the data are given in the first table and the result in the last, calculations are given by the paper I provided. My question is: if I change a bit my data, to what extent will the last matrix, the result matrix, change? Or more specifically : what method to use to know if it is robust or not ?

Comment: I have found that the article can be translated to English so I did that. Martin and Maronna is a standard robustness book.

Comment: The definition in wikipedia is that small changes in the data or model parameters do not affect the estimated parameters. I assume it really means has very little effect.

Comment: A good question here should be self-contained and not depend on reading external sources to be understood at all. Supporting references are fine, but the question must stand by itself.

Comment: @NickCox Okay, I'm developing on the way I used the method

Comment: @Scortchi is it clear now ?

Comment: @Marine1: Thanks! I think it's much clearer now.